# I lived in France for 8 months and then moved to the UK, how will I pay my tax next June?

Tags: taxes, france

I have worked in Paris from **Jan** to **Aug** (**8 months total** - French company) before moving back to London this September.

I know you can pay your taxes online if you have registered in person the first time, but since this will be my first time paying tax in France I cannot do that. And since I am not a resident anymore, I won't be able to go in person to my local office next June to do the registration.

What do I need to do? I do not speak French so I cannot find any information!

Additional information:

- I am an Italian national (but I have never accrued a salary in Italy, always in the UK).
- I do not have a Carte Vitale: I have applied for it in January and nothing has arrived since then.
- I do not speak French - which I know will make this process a lot more difficult!

Any help would be appreciated. I obviously want to pay my tax to avoid any issues in the future, but I also hope I won't have to go through hell to get this done - my 8 months there made me lose any hope in French bureaucracy!

Comment: There is something called "service des non-résidents" but obviously not speaking French and never having paid taxes in France before won't make things easy. See http://www.impots.gouv.fr/portal/dgi/public/popup?espId=1&typePage=cpr02&docOid=documentstandard_5953 and http://www.impots.gouv.fr/portal/dgi/public/popup?espId=1&typePage=cpr02&docOid=documentstandard_5953

Comment: Not an answer, but a quick google search: you might retain the services of a bilingual French tax attorney, such as this one http://www.french-tax-lawyer.j2m-online.fr/

Comment: Some clues here :http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6124/french-taxes-have-not-received-any-documentation-and-i-have-moved-out-of-the-co?rq=1